# Snakemake touch command

Tags: snakemake

I use snakemake and I tried to write a work-flow on alignment and create bigwig.
I would like to introduce a creation after star alignment on a file to use for  gave me a way to run the  wig generation only after all the samples are aligned.

I have this error:

```
  snakemake --core 3 --configfile config_tardis.yml  -np
RuleException in line 40 of /home/centos/rna_test/rules/star2.rules:
Could not resolve wildcards in rule star_map:
sample
```

I tried to use this code:

```
rule star_map:
    input:
        dt="trim/{sample}/",
        forward_paired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_forward_paired.fq.gz",
        reverse_paired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_reverse_paired.fq.gz",
        forward_unpaired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_forward_unpaired.fq.gz",
        reverse_unpaired="trim/{sample}/{sample}_reverse_unpaired.fq.gz",
        t1p="database.done",
    output:
        out1="ALIGN/{sample}/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam",
        out2=touch("Star.align.done")
    params:
        genomedir = config['references']['basepath'],
        sample=config["samples"],
        platform_unit=config['platform'],
        cente=config['center']
    threads: 12
    log: "ALIGN/log/{params.sample}_star.log"
    shell:
        'STAR --runMode alignReads  --genomeDir {params.genomedir} '
        r' --outSAMattrRGline  ID:{params.sample} SM:{params.sample} PL:{config[platform]}  PU:{params.platform_unit} CN:{params.cente} '
        '--readFilesIn   {input.forward_paired} {input.reverse_paired} {input.forward_unpaired} {input.reverse_unpaired} \
       --readFilesCommand zcat \
       --outStd Log \
       --outSAMunmapped Within \
       --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate \
       --runThreadN  {threads} --outFileNamePrefix  {output.out1};{output.out2}  2> {log} '




rule star_wigg_file:
    input:
        f1= "ALIGN/{sample}/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam",
        t1p="Star.align.done",
    output:
        "ALIGN/{sample}/wiggle/"
    threads: 12

    shell:
       'STAR --runMode inputAlignmentsFromBAM -inputBAMfile {input.f1} --outWigType wiggle \
  --outWigStrand Stranded '
```

So, the problems seem associated on the introduce of touch

Comment: I think the issue with the touch is that it's lacking wildcards. I believe you need to have the same wildcards in all your output files. Can I ask why you specifically have to "touch" files? One of the reasons our group moved from GNU Make to Snakemake was so that we could eliminate the bad practice of using proxy files (touching files of size 0Kb) to coordinate larger pipelines. I don't immediately see the logic in your need to touch. Could you elaborate on it? Snakemake wont try to start aligning it all until everything is done anyways, so again, not sure why touch is needed.

Comment: thanks so much for the help. I try to use touch because I want  they perform the analysis only when all the other modules  are complete. Here I want the star_wigg file  are processed as last command. What is the way to achieve this?

Comment: When you say "all the other modules are complete", which ones are you talking about? If you put the output of other modules inside Star_Wigg, then the rule will wait for those outputs too. Inputs can come from multiple rules, and often do. Can you edit your post to include the other "rules" that you want "Star_Wigg" to wait for? These will be important to now include inside the input directive of Star_Wigg. Then Star_Wigg will know to wait for all the input files (best practice) not just a single proxy file (poor design).

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any mechanism for Snakemake to being determining the value of {sample}. At the furthest most output of Snakemake, is an explicit string. Snakemake needs this string to compare and try to match the patterns of each rule's output(s).

I like to define {sample}, as an expand, as the input of the rule all, [as per the author's suggestion](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/configuration.html#standard-configuration).

- It allows for the preservation of the core code-base (I.E. nothing is being constantly edited in the code you are running over and over again, or trying to preserve for auditing and reproducibility).
- It also provides a template for when comparing the amongst rules; if they all contain the word "{sample}", comparing inputs and outputs across rules will be easier, they should be identical. It's makes it much easier for others to notice your two rules are linked without running the code.

Add something like this to the top of your current file, and define a list of samples "sampleLIST" in config_tardis.yml:

**In the Snakefile as the top-most rule:**

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("ALIGN/{sample}/wiggle", sample=config["sampleLIST"])
```

**In the configuration file config_tardis.yml add:**

```
sampleLIST: ['Patient1','Patient2','Patient3']
```

On a side note, as per the comments. I'm also interested in addressing the use of touch. The intent being that a pipeline design should rely on Snakemake's dependency determination for real output files. The file "Star.align.done" seem's like a proxy file, if so, there might be another way without it.

Comment: thanks so much for you help and description. it is true..its a proxy file for the step of indexing of reference using star. Unfortunately I try many times to use touch..now i know it is wrong.. For example I want the wigg file was created after all the samples encoded n config_tardis.yml are aligned. If I try to use in that way the process wigg process start in the same time of  the alignment process. Another example: ALIGN, COUNT  AND then you want to run multiqc. How can define the dat I want all the samples have all that files?

Comment: Then we should try to get rid of that proxy file. Would you be interested in re-post as another question, so we can address, log, discuss it specifically?